# Repository UUID equivalent

Tags: git, svn, repository, uuid

I am converting an old Subversion repository to Git. Here is an example:

```
$ svn info http://alfa.com/bravo/charlie
Path: charlie
URL: http://alfa.com/bravo/charlie
Relative URL: ^/charlie
Repository Root: http://alfa.com/bravo
Repository UUID: 01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef
```

Does Git have some equivalent to *Repository UUID*?

Comment: Why? What do you want to use it for? What is your goal?

Comment: You could use the url or the root-hash. But without context it's hard to advise you.

Answer (score 3):

No, [there is no unique identification for a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34874343/560648).